# Flask SQL-Alchemy result append to list

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I making a query with **Flask-SQLAlchemy**, and then append the result to a list.
Here is the snippet of my code:

```
students_payment = db.session.query(Payment, Student, Course).join(Student, Course).distinct(Payment.student_id)

student_per_course = []
for data in students_payment:
    student_per_course.append({data.Course.name: [{data.Payment.payment_for_month.value: students_payment.filter(Payment.payment_for_month == data.Payment.payment_for_month).count()}]})
```

When I print the `student_per_course` variable I got a result like this:

```
[{'Tahsin': [{'January': 1}]}, {'Arabic Language': [{'September': 1}]}, {'Arabic Language': [{'August': 2}]}, {'Arabic Language': [{'August': 2}]}]
```

There is duplicate value on a month, which is August in this query result.

Then I try to remove the duplicate value with this [following code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41704662/8070090):

```
list_of_unique_dicts = []
for dict_ in student_per_course:
    if dict_ not in list_of_unique_dicts:
       list_of_unique_dicts.append(dict_)
```

And here is the result when I print the `list_of_unique_dicts`:

```
[{'Tahsin': [{'January': 1}]}, {'Arabic Language': [{'September': 1}]}, {'Arabic Language': [{'August': 2}]}]
```

The duplicate value on the month has been removed, but one of the key of the dictionary still got a duplicate value.

The result what I want is like this:

```
[
    {
        'Tahsin': [
            {'January': 1}
        ]
    },
    {
        'Arabic Language':
            [
                {'September': 1,
                 'August': 2
                 }
            ]
    },
]
```

In the result above, the result on `Arabic Language` keys are merged to all of the value from the keys.

So, the point of my question is, what's wrong in my query..?, in what point should I modify it..?, or should I thinking to merged the result on Python directly, no in SQLALchemy..?

Comment: The best place to fix this is in your SQLAlchemy query. Carefully look at what the join is doing and make sure you are filtering the duplicates you intend.

Comment: Also, a more sensible end result may be `{'Tahsin': {'January': [1]}, 'Arabic Language': ['September': [1], 'August': [2]}}` You don't really need the outer array it seems, and this would be a much easier data structure to construct.